# Windows "You don't have permission to access /" identical virtual host fails

Tags: windows-server-2008, apache-2.4

I've read many of the related permissions posts on StackOverflow and others and do not see why my virtual hosts for Apache2.4 on Windows 2008 appears to work inconsistently. The main site is running Drupal and the other one is essentially a clone of it that I want to run on port 8080 as an example in Apache's documentation.

In httpd.conf I have

```
Listen 80
Listen 8080
```

The one for port 80 works, but the one for 8080 returns the 403 error page.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot C:/Server/DOM
    ServerName example.edu
    <Directory C:/Server/DOM>
      Options FollowSymlinks
      AllowOverride All
      Require all granted
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:8080>
    DocumentRoot C:/Server/uat
    ServerName example.edu
    <Directory C:/Server/uat>
      Options FollowSymlinks
      AllowOverride All
      Require all granted
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Since this is Apache 2.4, the Require all granted is needed. The top one works, but the bottom one does not. I have compared the permissions on each directory and do not see any difference. The .htaccess is copied from the working one.

Apache returns this in its error log:

```
AH01797: client denied by server configuration: C:/Server/uat/
```

The only clue I'm seeing is when I remove the virtual host for port 80 and run https.exe -S

As you can see it's pulling in the default server and recognizes the config for the virtual host. I don't see any errors but clearly something I'm doing is wrong. Please show me what I should check next.

```
C:\Users\wattsg>c:\Apache24\bin\httpd.exe -S
VirtualHost configuration:
*:8080                 example.edu (C:/Apache24/conf/extra/httpd-v
hosts.conf:25)
ServerRoot: "C:/Apache24"
Main DocumentRoot: "C:/Server/DOM"
Main ErrorLog: "C:/Server/DOM/logs/error.log"
Mutex ssl-stapling-refresh: using_defaults
Mutex rewrite-map: using_defaults
Mutex ssl-stapling: using_defaults
Mutex ssl-cache: using_defaults
Mutex default: dir="C:/Apache24/logs/" mechanism=default
PidFile: "C:/Apache24/logs/httpd.pid"
Define: DUMP_VHOSTS
Define: DUMP_RUN_CFG
```

I have also checked the Windows Server to ensure that inbound ports for Apache24 are open for all.

Answer (score 2):

It comes down to how defaults for virtual servers are set in Apache 2. In the httpd.conf file I read that the default server would be overridden by any virtual server. I misread that. The config in httpd.conf defines the defaults. The virtual server setups can then alter them individually. My first mistake was that the main root site defined in this file ruled. That's why it always showed up. My second problem was that even though I defined the Directory rules correctly, I thought. It still refused permission even though I used the Apache 2.4 Require All Granted. This adjustment, which I have set up in the main conf file, allowed it to run. I hope it's secure from what I've been reading.

Allow from all

Require all granted

Answer (score 0):

It depends of Apache version
Since Apache 2.2

```
<Directory your/path>

...

Allow from all

...

</Directory>
```

with Apache 2.4

```
<Directory your/path>

...

Require all granted

...
</Directory>
```

According to the documentation you can read in paragraph "Protect Server Files by Default" of [Apache 2.2 Security Tips](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/misc/security_tips.html) and [Apache 2.4 Security Tips](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/misc/security_tips.html).
Apache 2.2 is no longer mantained, so I suggest to update to 2.4 for keeping safe your host and to recheck your configuration reading documentation about this version. I suggest to check your custom rows in config file reading [here](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html).

Comment: Hi @Lorenzo and welcome on serverfault. You might consider adding some more details and explanation of your suggested solution and WHY it will work. [This](https://serverfault.com/help/how-to-answer) might turn to be an intresting read.

Comment: I updated my answer. I hope you find it complete enough. I don't know why Apache HTTPD development team decided to remove <i>Allow</i> directive by configurations, but this is.